# Create offset with ion-slides. User should see the next broached slides

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm learning ionic and would like to create a horizontal scroll with ion-slides. The user should see the next slides but only broached. See in my image below. Later i will loop trough all elements with *ngFor. I'm using ionic2 and angular2

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<h3>For some sweet cocktails</h3><br>
  <ion-slides
    class="slide-wrapper"
    slidesPerView="2"
    spaceBetween="10"
    autoplay="4300"
    loop="true" >
    <ion-slide>
      <div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(assets/img/bar.jpg)','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover', 'border-radius': '15px','display': 'block' }" class="inner2 center" >
        <h1>Sin é</h1>
        <h4>Live Music</h4>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(assets/img/bar.jpg)','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover', 'border-radius': '15px','display': 'block' }" class="inner2 center" >
        <h1>Sin é</h1>
        <h4>Live Music</h4>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(assets/img/bar.jpg)','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover', 'border-radius': '15px','display': 'block' }" class="inner2 center" >
        <h1>Sin é</h1>
        <h4>Live Music</h4>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: I have ionic 1 solution, if you want http://plnkr.co/edit/5tYKfS?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! But i was not able to implement it with ionic 2. Did you found something, which makes this possible? @varunaaruru

Comment: hey did you solved this..I got the requirement like this now  :/

Comment: hey @varunaaruru i used this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper for the offset use float values in the config object.

Comment: @varunaaruru for example: ```config = {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 1.8,
    centeredSlides: false,
    paginationClickable: true,
    spaceBetween: 10
  }; ```

Comment: thank you very much..it worked..write it as answer and close..there are many open questions on this topic in SO and forum.

Comment: @varunaaruru I'm having the same issue but for my code it's not allowing 1.8, only full numbers. Also, I'm putting in the options into the `ion-slide`, like this `slidesPerView="1"`. Anything I'm missing? Been tearing my hair out on this for the past 5-6 hours...

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner yes.. ion-slides dont allow floating numbers..you have to use swiper api mentioned in above comments..I will post answer as soon as I get my laptop..(currenlt commenting via another machine)

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner please check the answer and let me know if you have any queries.. i have used `1.1` in my code you can change it to any number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

github [repo](https://github.com/varunaaruru/multislides-ionic2-3)

First install swiper in ionic app,

> **npm install --save angular2-useful-swiper**

add swiper.css and swiper.js files to index.html of ionic app

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

import swiper-module in appmodule.ts file

```
import { SwiperModule } from 'angular2-useful-swiper';
```

and add it in imports array..

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    SwiperModule
  ],
```

in the html file of the page where you want to use slides,

```
<ion-content>
<swiper [config]="config">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:red;">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:yellow;">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:green;">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:red;">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:yellow;">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:green;">Slide 6</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:red;">Slide 7</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:yellow;">Slide 8</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:green;">Slide 9</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-color:red;">Slide 10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </swiper>
</ion-content>
```

we will use the `config` in .ts file to customize the slider..for ex.

```
config: Object = {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            slidesPerView: 1.2, //use any number 1.8 or 4.2 or 7.3 etc..
            direction: 'horizontal',
            parallax: true,
            freeMode: false,
            fade: {
                crossFade: true,
            },
            allowSwipeToPrev: true,
            roundLengths: false,
            effect: 'slide' //use cube,flip,coverflow or fade
        };
```

output will be like this..[image: output]